# Osascript via Cron cannot send keystrokes (MacOS)

Tags: macos, automation, cron, applescript

I have a AppleScript script that I am running through Cron. Within it, contains a line:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using {command down}
```

This works fine when I run it locally, via `osascript script.scpt`.

However, when I run it through Cron, the mailed result says:

```
execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed to send keystrokes. (1002)
```

Here is my crontab for running the script, written through `crontab -e`:

```
25 * * * * osascript /Users/eric/scripts/script.scpt
```

How can I make allow the keystrokes to go through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working. I had to explicitly give it permission via Security and Privacy:

System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Accessibility -> Plus button

Then select the Cron executable, which is stored at `/usr/sbin/cron`. That's all it took!